# An extended Bezier Library or Algorithms of bezier operations

Tags: python, algorithm, bezier, curve

Is there a library of data structures and operations for quadratic bezier curves? I need to implement:

- bezier to bitmap converting with arbitrary quality
- optimizing bezier curves
- common operations like subtraction, extraction, rendering etc.

languages: c,c++,.net,python
Algorithms without implementation (pseudocode or etc) could be useful too. (especially optimization)

Comment: what do you mean by "subtraction" -- you mean you want to do set operations on regions bounded by bezier splines?

Comment: @SamB: yes. operations on regions of closed bezier splines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/). I am not exactly sure if it covers all your requirements but it should be able to handle rendering at least.

Comment: thanx. could i use carrio in .net ?

Comment: Cairo is closely related to GTK, and the Mono project has an assembly for it: http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Cairo

Answer (score 4):

A little bit of python lib is included in nodebox:

http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Bezier

There are plenty of algorithms inside inkscape, but I did not digg the code yet to find, how easy they could be used outside if inkscape.

Update: Inkscape is using lib2geom:

> lib2geom (2Geom in private life) was
>   initially a library developed for
>   Inkscape but will provide a robust
>   computational geometry framework for
>   any application. It is not a rendering
>   library, instead concentrating on high
>   level algorithms such as computing arc
>   length.

lib2geom is at http://lib2geom.sourceforge.net